# Logical error in simple acronym generator

Tags: c#

I have some kind of logical error in my program. Whenever I enter a phrase with 1 letter I get a ArgumentOutOfRange Exception, and whenever I enter a multiple letter word the textbox clears, displays "Apple" (the first value in my array) and does nothing else. Can anybody see the logical error in this?

```
string[] d = { "Apple", "Bass", "Cat", "Dog", "Ear", "Flamingo", "Gear", "Hat", "Infidel", "Jackrabbit", "Kangaroo", "Lathargic", "Monkey", "Nude", "Ozzymandis", "Python", "Queen", "Rat", "Sarcastic", "Tungston", "Urine", "Virginia", "Wool", "Xylophone", "Yo-yo", "Zebra", " " };
string var;
int len = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var = textBox2.Text;
    textBox1.Text = "";
    for (int y = 0; y < var.Length; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < d.Length; x++)
        {
            if (d[x].ToUpper().Substring(0, 0) == var.ToUpper().Substring(len, len))
            {
                len = len + 1;
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "\n" + d[x];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have removed irrelevant code. You should always post only part that is relevant to the question.

Comment: there is a lot of smelly thing you will discover yourself by debugging your code. place a breakpoint in button1_Click and you will discover it.

Answer (score 0):

`Substring(0, 0)` is really pointless. This will always be an empty string.

`Substring(len, len)` also is a bad idea, because it will return a string of length `len` starting at index `len`. This is where you get your exception.

I assume, what you really want is the second parameter to be 1 in both cases. And that can be further simplified to an access via index:

```
d[x].ToUpper()[0] == var.ToUpper()[len]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same quite easily using LINQ:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dict = d.ToDictionary(x => x.First(), x => x);
    textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, textBox2.Text.Select(x => dict[char.ToUpper(x)]));
}
```

To do it without LINQ I would suggest following:

```
for (int y = 0; y < input.Length; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < d.Length; x++)
    {
        if (char.ToUpper(d[x][0]) == char.ToUpper(input[y]))
        {
            result = result + "\n" + d[x];
        }
    }
}
```

Changes are:

- you don't need `len` variable. Use `y` instead.
- you don't need whole `string` uppercased. Use `char.ToUpper` static method instead.
- you don't need `string.Substring` method. Use indexers instead.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm fairly inexperienced in C# and was using my knowledge from other languages to make this. I didn't know you could index strings that way. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This line explains the behavior.

```
if (d[x].ToUpper().Substring(0, 0) == var.ToUpper().Substring(len, len))
```

Second parameter of substring is string length. So on the left you always have an empty string. On the right you also have empty string when len==0 (that's why your code always picks Apple).

After that you change len, and repeat the loop. Then expression on the right is var.Substring(1,1) which gives you the error if your string is 1 character long. Because this reads - 1 symbol starting with 1 (which is second character of the string)

Apart from that, the purpose of the code is complete mystery, so there are definitely other errors.